# VSCode doesn't recognize JS-Expression in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I started to work with Angular for a work-related project and am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OHbjep_WjQ&t=1874s (minute 50:30)

Which led me to following code-snippet

```
  i=0;
  doSomeHeavyTask()
  {
    console.log('Called ${this.i++} times');
  }
```

The browser should print following message into the console:

Called 0 times

Called 1 times

...

But VSCode doesnt recognize

```
${this.i++}
```

as an JS-expression, therefore it prints just the plain text.
The syntax also doesn't get highlighted and is handled like a normal string.

I can't find the reason behind this behaviour and couldn't find any other person with that problem. I would be happy if somebody could come up with a suggestion or a solution :)

Comment: For that to work you need to use template literals, i.e. `console.log(\`Called ${this.i++} times\`);`. Wrap the template literals with backticks (`\``) and not quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the wrong character for the template literal syntax. It should be the backtick (on keyboard, usually left of the 1 key), not the single quotation mark.

```
console.log(`Called ${this.i++} times`);
```